# Spanish Text is not correctly encoded in ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, character-encoding, actionscript-2

I have an XML that contains Spanish text. I noticed that when I traced out this XML to a string characters that contain accents where not correctly represented. I tested this by tracing out a single character, "è" and the output is "Ã©"

```
trace("è");    //outputs Ã©
```

How is this resolved in ActionScript? Thanks!!

Sample of the XML that is affected:

```
    '<month name="month6"> ' +
                            '<link.content document-href="tn5684" section-href="tn5687" document-type="SPECIAL-TOPIC" rank="1" link-url="">Bebé prematuro</link.content> ' +
                            '<link.content document-href="tn8416" section-href="tn8416" document-type="DP-TOPIC" rank="2" link-url="">¿Cómo puedo tomar decisiones informadas sobre mi bebé extremadamente prematuro?</link.content> ' +
                        '</month> ' +
```

The text appears in a List Component. I am changing the font around to find one that might work but this is not working. Anyone know how to represent accented characters in a List component??

**Update**

Loading the XML document from an external file does not have the same problem:

> var myXML:XML = new XML();
>   myXML.load("someXmlFile.xml");
>   //This works

However I need this xml to be built into the SWF. So am creating the XML from a string:

```
var xmlString:String = "<root><textNode>bebè</textNode></root>";
var myXML:XML = new XML(xmlString);   //This breaks the encoding?!
```

**Sorry Gang**
So I was using Flash Develop to edit the actionscript that contains the xml. This was apparently not encoding the text correctly. Opening this file in CS5, editing it, saving fixed the issue. DUH!

Comment: Please provide some more information about your XML

Comment: I can but did you see the above trace example? The problem appears to be unrelated to the xml.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is because this is likely to be a character encoding issue. That leaves 3 options: 1) The xml 2) Your project or compiler encoding setting 3) Your font

Comment: Ill try and change the font. According to Snote the console does not support accented characters.

Comment: Well this is a list component.. Are you saying that setting the font to Courrier New should work?

Answer (score 1):

Accents are not supported in the console

Comment: Ok.. well the accents are not represented correctly in the flash control either. I will change the font; see if that works.

Comment: The font is Courrier New and it support accents so it's not because of the font but the console just doesn't support it

Comment: Courrier New is the default font!